# How to close a modal in JS which is opened by "data-target"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a modal template in the same HTML file as controller.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDeleteItem">Delete selected item</button>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalDeleteItem">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title bold">Modal title here</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body pd-xlg">
            Modal content here
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.deleteItem()">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to close the modal in the **deleteItem** function. How can I get a modal instance within the deleteItem function to use?

I don't wanna create a component because it's just a simple modal.
Using $uibModal.open needs to pass a templateUrl, but I don't wanna create an individual HTML file for this modal template.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it now.

```
deleteItem() {
    var element = angular.element('#modalDeleteItem');
    element.modal('hide');
}
```